# Selenium - Clicking on a flash button which should open a new tab

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I  want to click on flash button which should open a new tab and in turn I need to do some operations on that page and return to the main page. Can anyone help with the code in Java? I have seen that flash doesn't work on Selenium, if so what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried, but i found this link, http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html, maybe is useful for you. Is a plugin to use selenium in Flash front end